# How to investigate a difference of behaviour between internet explorer and a .NET WebControl browser to connect to a facebook flash game

Tags: .net, facebook, winforms, internet-explorer, flash

The context: 
- I have on one hand internet explorer executing successfully a flash game on facebook.
- On the other hand I am working on a product which embeds a windows .NET webcontrol browser.
The registry feature control keys of IE and the ones of my product have been set to be identical.
edit: (I am not working on the flash game but on the embedded browser)

The problem:
The expected behavior would be that the embedded browser would run the flash game as well as IE.
However in the facts, the embedded browser is not loading the facebook flash game totally: what should be the game content stays a black screen instead of loading.

From here, I have no idea where to start my investigation and how to investigate. I would like to compare what happens in both case to know what are the cause of the difference of behaviours, however I don't know if it is a cookie problem, or some authorization refused, or some cache not filled.

Would someone have some advice to know where to start?

Comment: Most modern browsers are stopping Flash support. Chrome doesn't support it at all anymore. IE is severly restricting it's use. Basically Flash is dead time to move on

Comment: Interesting link, thanks.

Comment: *In December, Chrome 55 will make HTML5 the default experience, except for sites which only support Flash. For those, you’ll be prompted to enable Flash when you first visit the site.* the ultimate goal is to drop flash support altogether because it's 2016 and better solutions now exist

Comment: @RobertBerte consider... Does your embedded browser have Flash enabled? When you right-click over the black area does it say _"movie not loaded"_? Are you loading Flash from an https location? (if not, then try an https link to some swf as test)...

Comment: Yes the Flash browser is enabled. In fact it is even worse that what I have described: the flash game is running for the first launch, but it does not launch anymore after having closed it (without even logging out of facebook). That's why I guess that it is not a adobe flash problem but more something linked to the app itself, the cookies, the cache, the app fb.logout() or something. I just feel powerless to determine what it could be. And even more powerless considering that it is working on IE beside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being totally unable to investigate this error, I have just wandered the internet until I could find someone else who had the same problem, and indeed someone did:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2009/08/06/problems-with-flash-content-in-the-webbrowser-control/

There is a workaround to my own bug -which is in fact an adobe flash bug-: 
to remove manually the cached ".swf" (https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/kb/262110), see the "solution" section.

There is also an answer of how to investigate that kind of specific problem in the troubleshooting section:

1. use the developper tools included in internet explorer.
2. use a debugging tool as fiddler and investigate traces.
3. isolate the webbrowser code in the application to the strict minimum
4. try settings on the trusted zone for crossdomain

Thanks to Johanst for his former investigation (7 years ago) if he ever reads these lines.

adobe record:
(http)bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2919430

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279742/webbrowser-control-and-adobe-flash-content